# How do I capture mouseover events on dynamically-added input HTML elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mouseover

I am dynamically adding `input` elements to a `table` with the `id` of `inputDataElements`.

These `input` elements have the name `deleteAction`:

```
function renderInputDataRows(inputData) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    var rows = "";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    for (var i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        rows += '<tr>' +                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            // ...  
            '<td class="rowActions">' + \
            '<input type="image" ' + \
            '      style="position:relative; ' + \
            '               bottom:-2px; ' + \
            '                 left:-4px; ' + \
            '        padding-right:2px;" ' + \
            '       src="images/delete.png" ' + \
            '   onClick="deleteInputDataRow(' + inputData[i].index + ');"' + \
            '      name="deleteAction" ' + \
            '     value="deleteInputDataRow' + inputData[i].index + '"' + \
            '      size="18,18" ' + \
            '    border="0" />' + \
            '</td>' +
            // ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            '</tr>';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    return rows;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

**Question**: I would like to capture `mouseover` events on the `deleteAction`-named `input` elements.

I have the following jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    inputDataElementsRowDeleteActions = $("#inputDataElements input:[name=deleteAction]");
    ...
    inputDataElementsRowDeleteActions.mouseover(function(event) {
        alert(event);
    });
});
```

**Problem**: I do not get the `alert` message when I mouseover the `input` element.

Is there a way to capture the `mouseover` event with jQuery, when the elements are added dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `.live()`

```
inputDataElementsRowActions.live('mouseover', function(event) {
    alert(event);
});
```

or you could use `.delegate()` which is similar (and probably preferred in this case).

```
$("#inputDataElements").delegate('input[name=rowAction]', 'mouseover', function(event) {
    alert(event);
});
```

They both work by capturing the event that bubbles up. `.live()` captures it at the root, while `.delegate()` captures it at the `#inputDataElements` in this case.

- http://api.jquery.com/live/
- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Otherwise, you would have to bind the event as (or after) you create the elements.

Comment: When is delegate not preferred?

Comment: @redsquare - I suppose if you have no way of knowing into which part of the DOM the elements will be appended. It would be a rare case I would imagine. `.live()` is overused in my opinion.